# changing the state of the variable from the child component using custom event

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex3

this is the main application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
            verticalAlign="middle"
            backgroundColor="white" layout="absolute" initialize="init();"  xmlns:MyComp="screens.*" >
            <mx:Script>
                <![CDATA[
                import screens.MyEvent;

                    private function init():void
                    {
                         systemManager.addEventListener("data_transfer",handleDataTransfer);

                    }
                    private function handleDataTransfer(evt:MyEvent):void{

               this.myViewStack.selectedIndex=1;

                 }


                ]]>
            </mx:Script>


    <mx:ViewStack id="myViewStack" selectedIndex="0" width="1110" height="636">
    <MyComp:Welcome />
        <MyComp:Screen id="fillPage" />
        </mx:ViewStack>
    </mx:Application>
```

this is my Welcome component

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="930" height="300" >
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
       private function changeHandler():void{
        var myEVT:MyEvent = new MyEvent("data_transfer",false, true);
        this.dispatchEvent(myEVT);
       }

    ]]>
</mx:Script>
 <mx:Button label="Fill The Form" id="fillForm" click="changeHandler()"/>           
</mx:Canvas>
```

this is my screen.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="400" height="300">
<mx:Label text="hai">
</mx:Label> 
</mx:Canvas>
```

this is MYEvent.as

```
package screens
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class MyEvent extends Event
    {

    public static const DATA_TRANSFER:String = "data_transfer";

        public function MyEvent(type:String, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false)
        {
            super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
        }

    }
}
```

I want to get the Screen mxml by clicking the button at welcome mxml...i am initial learner..
 but it is not working..Please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your custom event has bubbling=false, it wont bubble upto the systemManager. try:

```
var myEVT:MyEvent = new MyEvent("data_transfer", true, true);
```

Alternatively, add the listener to the object that is dispatching the event:

```
welcomePage.addEventListener("data_transfer",handleDataTransfer);
....
<MyComp:Welcome id="welcomePage" />
```

Second solution is generally better/preferred - less event bubbling is a good thing

Comment: can we do this task without using events...In this case when a button is clicked(id=fillForm) can we write click="this.parent.myviewstack.currentIndex=1" something like this without using custom events..

Comment: yes you can - but the advantage of events is that they more flexible. if you decide to rearrange the layout of your components, you would have to manually adjust all the paths (this.parent.myComponent.etc).